# How to make visible mobile status bar in React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

How to make a visible mobile status bar in React Native Navigation

Screenshot: Status bar not visible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need import `StatusBar` and set hide:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';


    yourTriggerFunction() {
       StatusBar.setHidden(true);
    }
```